# A problem during a build of a Red-Black tree

Tags: c, tree

I have got a problem on this build of a Red-Black Tree. There is a segementation fault during insertFixUp  and so on. I don't know what to do.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    
    struct tree_node {
        int key; 
        int color;
        struct tree_node *parent;
        struct tree_node *left_child; 
        struct tree_node *right_child;
    };
    struct tree {
        int cardinality;
        struct tree_node *root;
        struct tree_node *Nil;
    };
    struct tree_node *getNewNode (int keys){
     struct tree_node* newNode = (struct tree_node*) malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
      newNode-> key = keys;
      newNode-> color = 0; 
      newNode-> parent = NULL;
      newNode-> right_child = NULL;
      newNode-> left_child = NULL;
    return newNode;
    }
    void TreeLeftRotate(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *x) {
        struct tree_node *y = x->right_child;
        x->right_child = y->left_child;
        if (y->left_child != T->Nil) {
            y->left_child->parent = x;
        }
        if (x->parent == T->Nil) {
            T->root = y;
        }
        else if (x == x->parent->left_child) {
            x->parent->left_child = y;
        }
        else {
            x->parent->right_child = y;
        }
        y->left_child = x;
        x->parent = y;
    }
    struct tree_node* BSTTreeMinimum(struct tree_node *x){
        if(x->left_child== NULL){
            return x;}
        else{
            return BSTTreeMinimum(x->left_child);}
    };
    struct tree_node *BSTTreeSearch(struct tree_node *x, int k){
        if ((x==NULL)||(x->key=k)){
            return x;
        }
        if(k<=x->key){
            return BSTTreeSearch(x->left_child, k);
        }
        else {
            return BSTTreeSearch(x->right_child, k);
        }
    }
    void BSTTreeInsert(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *z) {
        struct tree_node *x = NULL;
        struct tree_node *y = NULL;
        x = T->root;
        while (x!=NULL){
            y=x;
            if(z->key <= x->key){
                x=x->left_child;
            }
            else {
                x=x->right_child;
            }
        }
        z->parent =y;
        if(y==NULL){
            T->root = z;
        }
        if((y!=NULL)&&(z->key <= y->key)) {
            y->left_child = z;
        }
        if((y!=NULL)&&(z->key > y->key)) {
            y->right_child = z;
        }
    }
    
    void BSTTreeTransplant(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *u, struct tree_node *v){
        if (u->parent==NULL){
            T->root = v;
        }
        if((u->parent != NULL)&&(u=u->parent->left_child)){
            T->root = v;
        }
        if((u->parent!=NULL)&&(u=u->parent->right_child)){
            u->parent->right_child=v;
        }
        if(v!=NULL){
            v->parent = u->parent;
        }
    }
    
    void BSTTreeDelete(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *z){
        struct tree_node *y = NULL;
        if (z->left_child == NULL){
            BSTTreeTransplant(T,z,z->right_child);
        }
        if((z->left_child != NULL) && (z->right_child == NULL)){
            BSTTreeTransplant(T,z,z->left_child);
        }
        if((z->left_child != NULL)&&(z->right_child != NULL)){
            y=BSTTreeMinimum(z->right_child);
            if (y->parent != z){
                BSTTreeTransplant(T,y,y->right_child);
                y->right_child = z->right_child;
                y->right_child->parent =y;
            }
            BSTTreeTransplant(T,z,y);
            y->left_child = z->left_child;
            y->left_child->parent = y;
        }
    }
    
    void TreeRightRotate(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *x) {
        struct tree_node *y = x->left_child;
        x->left_child = y->right_child;
        if (y->right_child != T->Nil) {
            y->right_child->parent = x;
        }
        if (x->parent == T->Nil) {
            T->root = y;
        }
        else if (x == x->parent->right_child) {
            x->parent->right_child = y;
        }
        else {
            x->parent->left_child = y;
        }
        y->right_child = x;
        x->parent = y;
    }
    
    
    void RBTreeInsertFixUpLeft(struct tree*T, struct tree_node *z){
        struct tree_node *y = z->parent->parent->right_child;
        if (y->color == 1) {
            z->parent->color = 0;
            y->color = 0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            z=z->parent->parent;
        }
        else{
            if (z==(z->parent->right_child)){
                z=z->parent;
                TreeLeftRotate(T,z);
            }
            z->parent->color = 0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            TreeRightRotate(T,z->parent->parent);
        };
    };
    
    void RBTreeInsertFixUpRight(struct tree*T, struct tree_node *z){
        struct tree_node *y = z->parent->parent->left_child;
        if (y->color == 1) {
            z->parent->color = 0;
            y->color = 0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            z=z->parent->parent;
        }
        else{
            if (z==z->parent->left_child){
                z=z->parent;
                TreeRightRotate(T,z);
            }
            z->parent->color = 0;
            z->parent->parent->color=1;
            TreeLeftRotate(T,z->parent->parent);
        };
    };
    void RBTreeInsertFixup(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *z){
        while (z->parent->color = 1){ //segmentation fault
            if(z->parent == z->parent->parent->left_child){
                RBTreeInsertFixUpLeft(T,z);
            }
            else {
                RBTreeInsertFixUpRight(T,z);
            }
        }
        T->root->color=0;
    };
    void RBTreeInsert(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *z) {
        struct tree_node *y = T->Nil; 
        struct tree_node *x = T->root;
        while (x!=T->Nil){
            y=x; 
            if (z->key < x->key) {
                x=x->left_child;
            }
            else {
                x=x->right_child;
            }
        }
        z->parent = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        z->parent = y; 
        if (y==T->Nil){
            T->root = z;
        }
        if((y!=T->Nil)&&(z->key < y->key)){
            y->left_child=z;
        }
        if ((y!=T->Nil)&&(z->key >= y->key)){
            y->right_child = z;
        }
        z->left_child = T->Nil; 
        z->right_child = T->Nil;
        z->color = 1;
        RBTreeInsertFixup(T,z);
        };
    void RBTransplant(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *u, struct tree_node *v){
        if (u->parent == T->Nil) {
            T->root = v;
        }
        else if (u==u->parent->left_child){
            u->parent->left_child = v;
        }
            else {
            u->parent->right_child=v;
        }
        v->parent = u->parent;
        };
    void RBDeleteFixup(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *x){
        if (x == x->parent->left_child){
            struct tree_node *w = x->parent->right_child;
            if (w->color == 1) {
                w->color = 0;
                x->parent->color = 1;
                TreeLeftRotate(T,x->parent);
                w=x->parent->right_child;
            }
            if (w->left_child->color == 0 && w->right_child->color == 0){
                w->color = 1;
                x = x->parent;
            }
            else if (w->right_child->color == 0){
                w->left_child->color = 0;
                w->color = 1;
                TreeRightRotate(T,w);
                w = x->parent->right_child;
            }
            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = 0;
            w->right_child->color = 0;
            TreeLeftRotate(T,x->parent);
            x=T->root;
        }
        else {
            struct tree_node *w = x->parent->left_child;
            if (w->color == 1) {
                w->color = 0;
                x->parent->color = 1;
                TreeRightRotate(T,x->parent);
                w=x->parent->left_child;
            }
            if (w->right_child->color == 0 && w->left_child->color == 0){
                w->color = 1;
                x = x->parent;
            }
            else if (w->left_child->color == 0){
                w->right_child->color = 0;
                w->color = 1;
                TreeLeftRotate(T,w);
                w = x->parent->left_child;
            }
            w->color = x->parent->color;
            x->parent->color = 0;
            w->left_child->color = 0;
            TreeRightRotate(T,x->parent);
            x=T->root;
        }
    }
    void RBDelete(struct tree *T, struct tree_node *z) {
        struct tree_node *x = NULL;
        struct tree_node *y = z; 
        int y_original_color = y->color; 
        if (z->left_child == T->Nil){
            x = z->right_child;
            RBTransplant(T,z,z->right_child);
        }
        else if(z->right_child == T->Nil){
            x = z->left_child;
            RBTransplant(T,z,z->left_child);
        }
        else {
            y=BSTTreeMinimum(z->right_child);
            y_original_color = y->color;
            x = y->right_child;
            if (y->parent == z){
                x->parent = y;
            }
            else {
                RBTransplant(T,y,y->right_child);
                y->right_child = z->right_child;
                y->right_child->parent = y;
            }
            RBTransplant(T,z,y);
            y->left_child = z->left_child;
            y->left_child->parent = y; 
            y->color = z->color;
        }
         if (y_original_color == 0) {
            RBDeleteFixup(T, x);
        }
    }
    double SingleExperimentBST (int max_keys, int max_search, int max_delete, int max_instances) {
        int t_tot = 0;
        int t_elapsed = 0;
        clock_t t_start = 0, t_final = 0 ;
        int A[max_keys];
        int B[max_search];
        int C[max_delete];
       
        struct tree_node *z =NULL;                                                     
        z = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        struct nodo *x =NULL;                                                     
        x = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        
            for (int instance= 1; instance <= max_instances; instance++){ 
                 for (int j= 0; j < max_keys; j++){               
                    A[j] = 1 + rand() % 100;  }
                                      
                struct tree *T= NULL;                                                      
                T=malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
                t_start = clock();                                 
                for (int key =1; key<= max_keys; key++){
                    struct tree_node* z = getNewNode(A[key]);
                    z->parent = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
                    z->parent = getNewNode(A[key]);
                    BSTTreeInsert(T, z);
                }
                for (int key = 1; key<= max_search; key++){
                    B[key] = 1 + rand() % 100;  
                    int k= B[key];
                    struct tree_node *x = T->root;
                    BSTTreeSearch(x, k) ;
                }
                for (int key = 1; key<= max_delete; key++){
                    C[key] = 1 + rand() % 100;  
                    struct tree_node* z1 = getNewNode(C[key]);
                    BSTTreeDelete(T, z1) ;
                 }
                t_final = clock();
                t_elapsed = t_final - t_start;
                t_tot = t_tot + t_elapsed;
                T->root =NULL;         
            }
        t_final= t_tot / max_keys;
        return t_final;
        }
    double SingleExperimentRBT (int max_keys, int max_search, int max_delete, int max_instances){
        int t_tot = 0; 
        int t_elapsed =0;
        clock_t t_start = 0, t_end = 0 ;
        int A[max_keys];
        int B[max_search];
        int C[max_delete];
        struct tree_node *z =NULL;                                                      
        z = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        struct tree_node *x =NULL;                                                     
        x = malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
        for (int instance = 1; instance <=max_instances; instance++){
            struct tree *T= NULL;
            T=malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
            for (int j= 0; j < max_keys; j++){
                    A[j] = 1 + rand() % 100; 
            }
            t_start = clock();
            for (int key=1; key<=max_keys; key++) {
                struct tree_node *z = getNewNode(A[key]);
                RBTreeInsert(T, z);
            }
            for (int key = 1; key<= max_search; key++){
                B[key] = 1 + rand() % 100;  
                int k= B[key];
                struct tree_node *x = T->root;
                BSTTreeSearch(x, k) ;
            }
            for (int key = 1; key<= max_delete; key++){
                C[key] = 1 + rand() % 100;  
                struct tree_node* z1 = getNewNode(C[key]);
                RBDelete(T, z1) ;
                }
            t_end = clock();
            t_elapsed = t_end + t_elapsed;
            t_tot = t_tot + t_elapsed;
            T->root = NULL;
        }
        return t_tot/max_keys;
    }
    
    void Experiment(int min_keys, int max_keys){
        time_t t;
        int step = 10; 
        int max_instances = 5; 
        int percentage_search = 60;
        for (int keys = min_keys; keys<=max_keys; keys+step){
            srand((unsigned) time(&t));
            double max_search = keys*percentage_search/100;
            double max_delete = keys - max_search;
            double timeBST =SingleExperimentBST(keys, max_search, max_delete, max_instances);
            srand((unsigned) time(&t));
            double timeRBT = SingleExperimentRBT(keys, max_search, max_delete, max_instances);
            printf("%f\t\t\t%f\n", timeBST, timeRBT);
            t = t + 1;
        }
    }
        
    
    int main() {
        int min_key = 10;
        int max_key = 150;
        Experiment(min_key, max_key);
        return 0;
    }
```

This code should calculate the time of the operations of insertion, deletion, research on a RB Tree but it doesn't print anything. The code is quite complex and if there are some other errors please let me know. During the compilation it doesn't show anything. The Segmentation fault occurs during the debug.

Comment: Your code example is fairly big. Enable all compiler warnings and fix them. Run your code with a memory access checker, e.g. compile with `gcc -g -fsanitize=address,undefined -Wall -Wextra`. If you don't use `gcc` you can use an online IDE, e.g. http://onlinegdb.com. There you can use the gear wheel symbol to set extra compiler flags to `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined -Wall -Wextra` You have a possible endless loop `for (int keys = min_keys; keys<=max_keys; keys+step)`. Did you mean `keys+=step`?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (z->parent->color = 1){ //segmentation fault
```

This is an assignment `=`, not a comparison `==`.

Comment: The problem is that i tried also with " == " but it has got the same problem

Comment: Then you might have more than one problem. I only spotted this one.

Answer (score 0):

This code is in error

```
 void RBTreeInsertFixUpLeft(struct tree*T, struct tree_node *z){
        struct tree_node *y = z->parent->parent->right_child;
        if (y->color == 1) {
```

It is possible when having just inserted a node, the parent node exists but the uncle node may not. It may be NULL. So y may be NULL
But the "color" of a node is Black if NULL and the node->color if non-NULL
You should write an inline function that returns the colour of node
bool IsBlack(const tree_node *curr) { return (curr == NULL || curr->color == 0); }
and use that.

Note the same situation occurs with Delete Fixups.
If you delete a leaf black node and it has a parent, then the sibling exists and must be black, it is a real node. But the siblings children may not exist but they should be regarded as black. Your code on deletion must take this into account.